# UIView Animation Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.30f];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:viewSettings cache:YES];   
viewSettings.alpha = 0;
[viewSettings removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I ve written the code above that works well when I add the view via animation, but it doesn't work when i remove the view from superview. Animation works if I remove `[viewSettings removeFromSuperview]` line. I don't know where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove it from the superview *after* the animation has completed. This is very easy to accomplish if you use the blocks based API, which Apple is encouraging you to do:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:viewSettings 
                  duration:0.30f 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone  
                animations:^{ 
    [viewSettings setAlpha:0];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [viewSettings removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

You can read about all the options in [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationTransition).

Comment: THANKSSSSS A TON :) .... but bro tell me what u mean by blocks based API ??? sorry m newbie in iphone :)

Comment: Blocks enable you to package a section (or block) of code as an object and pass to methods and functions. [This guide from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009758) has plenty of detail.

Answer (score 1):

`removeFromSuperview` is not an animatable action, so it is getting performed immediately.  Once you `commitAnimations`, your view is no longer part of it's superview, so you can't see the animation, if it is still even happening.

If you want your animation to happen, then the view to get removed, call `removeFromSuperview` when the animation ends, such as in a selector specified with `setAnimationDidStopSelector:`.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing view after the animation is completed. Initially alpha value of the view is 1 then, you apply the animation and make it 0. Now the view is still there but it is not visible. Once the animation is over then remove the view. I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think `viewSettings` is removed before you commit the animation.
Try inverting the two last lines.